# Restrictions for the geometric series formula and why might $0^0 = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I was curious about how the restrictions for the geometric series formula arise from its proof, namely
that $|r|<1$. Here is the traditional proof (for the partial sum of a geometric series) that I'm familar with:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^n=s=a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\dots+ar^{n-1}$$
$$\implies rs=ar+ar^2+ar^3+\dots+ar^n$$
$$\implies s-rs=a-ar^n$$
$$\implies s=a\Big(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\Big)$$

Immediately we find that since the denominator contains $1-r$, then this formula restricts $r\neq1$. Continuing forward, we find that the infinite sum is simply the limit

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a\Big(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\Big)$$

Using simple tests for convergence, the limit only converges on the restriction that $|r|<1$. Considering $0<1$, there does not seem to be much indication (arising solely from the proof) that $r$ cannot be $0$. Naively so, we could evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 0^k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{1-0^n}{1-0}\Big)=1$$

Controversially, it seems this can be used as a tool to deduce a value for $0^0$.

$$\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty 0^n=1=0^0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty0^k$$
$$\implies 0^0=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty0^k$$

Since $0^k=0\ \ \ \forall k>0$, we find that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty0^k=0$$
$$\therefore 0^0=1$$

As we see, on the assumption that the geometric series formula works for all $|r|<1$, then $0^0=1$ follows. I feel that mathematicians are rolling in their grave at this, so

> What is the proof missing to show that $r\neq 0$?

**Edit:** Before making this post, I was under the impression (and education) that $0^0$ was undefined by convention. However it's clear to me now that this seems to be up for debate. Justification for either convention is something I'm very intrigued by.

Comment: Why wouldn't $0^0$ be $1$?

Comment: @azifmedrano I've been taught that it was undefined. Is that not true? WolframAlpha seems to be on team-undefined.

Comment: $0^0$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: $0^0$ being undefined isn't up to convention, it's determined by context. It's undefined if the exponent is taken from a continuous space (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), but it's $1$ if the exponent comes from $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I use $0^0=1$ also in your other contexts. It's simply a matter of saying that I define $0^0=1$ in those contexts. Expanding the definition of the power notation is already done like 3-4 times as you work your way from natural exponents to more general domains, so one more expansion can't be that disagreeable.

Comment: I don't tend view continuous exponentiation as an extension of discrete exponentiation, but this is all matters of convention. What I stated above is what I've seen used most commonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a context where your exponents are all integers, I have yet to see a single good reason why $0^0=1$ shouldn't be a convention. And I have seen several reasons why it should be (appealing to the empty product, using elementary combinatorics, and the application to geometric / power series being the three I can think of right now).

As such, setting $0^0$ to be equal to $1$ (at least for integer exponents) solves some issues and as far as I'm aware it raises no issues. It is therefore a good convention. It is also a pretty common convention.

I am partial to letting $0^0=1$ all the time. However, some people think the non-existence of $\lim_{x,y\to0^+}x^y$ (or similar limiting arguments) speaks against this definition in contexts where the exponent is allowed to be any (non-negative) real number. I do not think this is an issue, but to each their own.

Comment: I'm relieved to hear this. For a while now I thought I would receive stigma for my own belief that $0^0=1$. It being "a pretty common convention" is embarrassingly exhilarating.

Comment: My issue with this is that it is analytically inconsistent as a single variable limit depending on whether the exponent or base is fixed.   I also don’t care that much.

Answer (score 2):

A useful definition of exponentiation works for non-negative integer, or more generally , if $a,b$ are cardinalities of sets $A,B$, then $a^b$ is the cardinality of the set of functions $B\to A$. With this, $0^0$ quite naturally.

We can extend this definition largely by using $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$ whenever this is defined. This happens to coincide with the above where both are defined, namely when $x,y$ are finite positive integers. However, there are points where only one of the two definitions work, e.g., for $0^0$. This doesn't make the *expression*  retroactively *undefined*. Just like noting that often $xy=\exp(\ln x+\ln y)$ holds, doesn't make the product undefined for factors where the log is undefined.

Note however, that knowing $\lim x_n= 0$ and $\lim y_n=0$ does not allow us to conclude $\lim x_n^{y_n}=0^0=1$ or anything at all. That's why we say that $0^0$ is an *indeterminate form*. This is a wholly different concept.

Comment: Re. your final paragraph: Setting $0^0=1$ doesn't make the function $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ magically continuous at the origin. If you want it to be continuous, it can't be defined at the origin. I don't see an inherent reason why it should be continuous, though. As long as I know it's continuous outside the origin, I'm all good.

Answer (score 1):

$0^0$ is equal to $1$. There's too much needless confusion surrounding this. This is not a debatable point. It's not even a "convention"; it's just a fact. There is exactly one function from the empty set to the empty set. There are no ifs, ands or buts about this.

A part of the reason this "controversy" exists is because many highly voted past answers on this site insist that the value of $0^0$ is somehow up for debate or "undefined". Of course, these same people have no qualms in writing $e^x = \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That i if you define $a^b$ combinatorically. OP is talking *series*, i.e., analysis.

Comment: It doesn't matter. $1+1=2$ is a fact, regardless of whether we are in combinatorics-land or analysis-land. Likewise here. A mathematical statement about operations on natural numbers doesn't change depending on whether you're an analyst or a combinatorialist. $0^0$ is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $0^0$ is not defined.

As you state, it is clear from the definition of $a^k$ for integer $k \ge 1$:

$\begin{align*}
   a^k
     &= a                 \qquad k = 1 \\
     &= a^{k - 1} \cdot a \quad k > 1
\end{align*}$

To make $a^m \cdot a^n = a^{m + n}$ also if $m$ or $n$ are zero, we *define* $a^0 = 1$ **as long as $a \ne 0$**. To make $(a^m)^n = a^{m n}$ work out for $m$ rational, it is convenient to *define* $a^{1/m} = \sqrt[m]{a}$, again **as long as $a \ne 0$**.

To make $a^x$ continuous in $x$, we finally *define* $a^x = \exp(x \ln a)$. And again, this expression gets into trouble if $a = 0$.

To summarize: $0^0$ *is not defined*. Any definition of that will run into trouble, sooner or later.

It is common to take $0^0 = \lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1$ when working with series and the value turns up as the 0-th term of the series, but it is just a notational convenience (otherwise you'd have to single out the constant terms for endless hassle and no gain).

Comment: I think the last paragraph is important here.   It is a convenient convention.  If you instead had the variable in the exponent you would call it 0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"Any definition of that will run into trouble, sooner or later."*? Unless the principal of explosion is involved, setting $0^0=1$ doesn't seem to lead to a contradiction of anything fundamental.

Comment: @Randall "convenient convention" is just anoher wording for "definition"